# Script to calculate odd file size

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I need to write a script which will calculate a total size of files which size is odd number; could you help me please?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Directory <$1> contains the following filenames of odd size:"
ls -l $1 |
while read file_parm
do
        size=`echo $file_parm | cut -f 5 -d " "`
        name=`echo $file_parm | cut -f 9 -d " "`

        let "div=size%2"

        if [ ! -d $name ]
        then
                if [ $div -ne 0 ]
                then
                        # this is listing odd numbers from this
                        # directory; I just need to add them together
                        # and print result
                        echo "[$name : $size]"
                fi
       fi
done
```

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Your problem (assuming you tried adding size during the loop) is likely the fact that pipes spawn sub-shells and variable assignments can't escape that. Using a loop instead of `ls` will fix that problem and make your script better too.

Comment: Are you on Linux?  If so, I would probably use: `totsize=0; for file in "$1"/*; do if [ -f "$file" ]; then size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file"); if ((size % 2 == 1)); then echo "[$file : $size]"; ((totsize += $size)); fi; fi; done; echo "Total size of odd-sized files = $totsize"`.  If not, I'd probably get GNU's `stat` command (from `core-utils`) and use it, or write a surrogate that does the job (C, or Perl, or Python, or ...), etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, can be simpler: `stat -c '%s %n' "$1"/* | while read -r size name; do ...` -- add `%F` is you explicitly want to exclude directories (which in my experience are always a multiple of the (even) block size.

Comment: @glennjackman: unless you're careful, that runs into the problem with variables set in loops reading from a pipe do not affect the main shell.  I think there's a `shopt` option to affect that, or you can write code with an explicit subshell, etc.

Comment: Do not attempt to destroy your question after you've been given answers.

Comment: @glennjackman: the [`shopt -s lastpipe`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) runs the last command in a pipeline in the current shell, avoiding problems with modifying variables in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I virtually copied the code from my comment and ran it, and it worked -- I just had to ensure I had `$1` set to somewhere sane, rather than empty.

```
$ set -- "."; totsize=0; for file in "$1"/*; do if [ -f "$file" ]; then size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file"); if ((size % 2 == 1)); then echo "[$file : $size]"; ((totsize += $size)); fi; fi; done; echo "Total size of odd-sized files = $totsize"
[./bash-assoc-arrays.sh : 417]
[./makefile : 1125]
[./xx.pl : 117]
Total size of odd-sized files = 1659
$
```

Or, formatted for readability:

```
set -- "."
totsize=0
for file in "$1"/*
do
    if [ -f "$file" ]
    then
        size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")
        if ((size % 2 == 1))
        then
            echo "[$file : $size]"
            ((totsize += $size))
        fi
    fi
done
echo "Total size of odd-sized files = $totsize"
```

The repeated invocation of `stat` is a bit expensive.  If you don't have files with newlines in their names (most people don't), you can speed it up with a single invocation of `stat` and some care:

```
stat -c '%s %F %n' "$1"/* |
{
totsize=0
while read size type name
do
    if [ "X$type" = "X-" ] && ((size % 2 == 1))
    then
        ((totsize+=$size))
        echo "[$name : $size]"
    fi
done
echo "Total size of odd-sized files = $totsize"
}
```

You could use `(...)` in place of `{...}` at a marginal (unmeasurable) cost in efficiency.

Answers to other questions explain the `[ "X$type" = "X-" ]` notation.